# Unable to Resolve host name in Xamarin Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.mac

I am trying to Get IP Address of Current Machine in Xamarin.Mac. I am using this C# Code and it's working in Windows very well but for Xamarin.But on Mac it throws an

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

.

Here is the code I'm Using:

```
public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();
        try
        {

            IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            combo_box.UsesDataSource = true;
            combo_box.Add(new NSString("127.0.0.1"));
            foreach (IPAddress item in IPHost.AddressList)
            {
                combo_box.Add(new NSString(item.ToString()));
            }

            Clients clt = GetLatestClient();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clt.ServerIP) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(clt.ipadd))
            {
                ServerIpAddress = clt.ServerIP;
                IpAddressVal = clt.ipadd;
                //ClientForm serverMaster = new ClientForm();
                //serverMaster.Show();
                //BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(Hide));
            }
        }
```

Here is exception that is being thrown:

> could not resolve host 'host name'

[Exception thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0rRd.png)

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm seeing this error also

Answer (score 0):

Does this work if you have a simple Console application?

It might not be Xamarin.Mac specific, but just an implementation difference with mono.